# How to set search scope to specific site or subsite using KQL powershell csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, keywordquery, kql-query

I want to search for content in a specific subsite in sharepoint online. How can  I set scope of search to subsite in KQL using powershell csom?

I tried the following query:

```
$queryText="createdby:$OldAuthor contentclass:STS_ListItem_850  OR (IsDocument:1 FileType:doc* FileType:pdf* FileType:xls* FileType:ppt*) -ContentTypeId:0x0120* -path:{$siteUrl} "
```

But path parameter did not work and I got results from entire tenant. How can I restrict it to specific subsite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `-path:{$siteUrl}` try `site:$($siteUrl)`, e.g.

`$siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/subsite"`

`$QueryText = " ... site:$($siteUrl)"`

Answer (score 1):

The character '-'(-path:) means Exclusion, I think you should remove it for your query.

[Check here for Official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#inclusion-and-exclusion-operators).